# Facebook FB.UI apprequests popup window doesn't close when user submits?

Tags: facebook, dialog

I'm using the FB.UI() javascript sdk to display an apprequests window to allow users to select friends to send requests to. Usually this "pops up" in a modal on the current page, and that works fine, it properly return the request_ids to the javascript on the originating page. But occasionally (randomly?) the popup appears as a completly new window that works just like the modal popup, EXCEPT when you click send requests the popup window redirects to something like http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect/xd_proxy.php?version=0.... and remains open with a blank page that contains this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>XD Proxy</title>
  </head>
  <body onload="doFragmentSend()">
    <div
      id="swf_holder"
      style="position: absolute; top: -10000px; width: 1px; height: 1px">
    </div>
    <script>
var XdCommUrl = "http:\/\/static.ak.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v1\/yF\/r\/Y7YCBKX-HZn.swf";var AllowFbCom = false;
/**
 * For "proxying" in-browser messages for Connect.
 *
 * @author naitik
 */
/**
 * Resolve a id back to a node. An id is a string like:
 *    top.frames[5].frames['crazy'].parent.frames["two"].opener
 *
 * @param   id {String}   the string to resolve
 * @returns    {Node}     the resolved window object
 * @throws  SyntaxError   if the id is malformed
 */ ...
```

There's more to the page than that. But the point is that the popup window remains open. If you close the window manually, the javascript code successfully starts again, but there is no "return data" like there is with a modal popoup.

Any ideas?

THanks,
Philip